# How to get error Referenced assembly 'xxxxxxxx' does not have a strong name

Tags: .net, dll, .net-assembly

I'm learning Strong naming and Signing assemblies and found that a signed assembly cannot reference unsigned assembly.

But i'm not able to reproduce this error.

I followed below steps:
1: Create a new class library project A.
2: Sign the project using Signing tab in project properties.
3: Create a new class library project B
4: Add reference of B.dll in project A. It gets added and builds successfully.

I tried .snk and .pfx both types of files.
Guide me on where i my understanding is wrong or which part i'm missing.

Comment: You are probably going too fast, you actually have to use a type from B in the code of A to trigger the diagnostic.  If you don't then the compiler eliminates the dependency and doesn't check it.  And beware that it is a warning, not an error.

Comment: Done. Still no error.

Comment: You can't get an error, it is a warning.  Warnings don't automatically activate the Error List window.  I can see the warning just fine on my machine when I try it, you can have it when you make me an offer I can't refuse.

Comment: thanks got the warning. but isn't it should be an error if it is not allowed to so.

Comment: It is not an error.  The strong name does not get checked when an app runs in full trust.  Which is about always.  So generating a compile-time error for something that doesn't actually cause a runtime error is not very useful.

Comment: oh understood. thanks